# ASM for Mac OS X

Tags: development

I've been very interested in learning ASM for a long time now and finally decided to get to it.
The problem is I have a MacBook and most of the books teach you based on DOS/Linux or MIPS.

Do you have any good tips for starters in ASM on a Mac OS X?

Comment: I think this is better suited to stackoverflow.com.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Stackover flow has a good answer on this exact question:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5649/x86-assembly-on-a-mac

Basically, XCode includes almost all of what you need for x86 Assembly